# Scope of variables inside anonymous functions in C#

Tags: c#, scope, anonymous-methods

I have a doubt in scope of varibles inside anonymous functions in C#.

Consider the program below:

```
 delegate void OtherDel(int x);

        public static void Main()
        {
            OtherDel del2;
            {
                int y = 4;
                del2 = delegate
                {
                      Console.WriteLine("{0}", y);//Is y out of scope
                };
            }

           del2();
        }
```

My VS2008 IDE gives the following errors:
[Practice is a class inside namespace Practice]

1.error CS1643: Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type 'Practice.Practice.OtherDel'
2.error CS1593: Delegate 'OtherDel' does not take '0' arguments.

It is told in a book: Illustrated C# 2008(Page 373) that the int variable y is **inside the scope of** del2 definition.
Then why these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problem;

1. you aren't passing anything into your `del2()` invoke, but it (`OtherDel`) takes an integer *that you don't use* - you still need to supply it, though (anonymous methods silently let you not declare the params if you don't use them - they still exist, though - your method is *essentially* the same as `del2 = delegate(int notUsed) {...}`)
2. the delegate (`OtherDel`) must return an `int` - your method doesn't

The scoping is fine.

Comment: #1 is completely correct, but #2: check out `OtherDel`'s type declaration at the top of the OP's code: `delegate void OtherDel(int x)` -- it doesn't return anything. [EDIT: this was changed in an edit to the question]

Comment: The answer reflects the question at the time I posted this ;p

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with scopes. Your delegate must return an integer value and take an integer value as parameter:

```
del2 = someInt =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", y);
    return 17;
};
int result = del2(5);
```

So your code might look like this:

```
delegate int OtherDel(int x);
public static void Main()
{
    int y = 4;
    OtherDel del = x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
        return x;
    };
    int result = del(y);
}
```